# Rename file if button is pressed in TreeView Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file, treeview

I have a treeview that displays a folder with text files. There is a 'open' button. That will open the file. But when this button is pressed it should rename the file to: `read filename.txt`. So if there is a file for example that is name `nameslist.txt` and the button is pressed it should rename it to `read nameslist.txt` or something similar. I thought of something like this:

```
void berichtenhistorie::on_Openbutton_released()
{
    QModelIndex index = ui->treeView->currentIndex();
    QString name = index.fileName();
    QString path = index.filePath();
    QFile file(path);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    file.rename("read " + name);
    file.close();
}
```

But this isnt working. I get the following error's:
`error: C2352: 'QDirModel::fileName' : illegal call of non-static member function`
But I dont know how to use `fileName()` and `filePath()` correctly.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that here is what you looking for:

```
void berichtenhistorie::on_Openbutton_released()
{
    QModelIndex index = ui->treeView->currentIndex();
    QFileSystemModel *model = (QFileSystemModel*)ui->treeView->model();
    QString path = model->filePath(index);
    QString name = model->fileName(index);
    QString dir = path;
    dir.remove(dir.size() - name.size(), name.size());
    QFile file(path);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        //Interact with the file
        file.close();
        if(file.rename(QString("%1read %2").arg(dir, name)))
                qDebug() << "Renamed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you open `file`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a break out of each step you'll need to do to work with QFile.

```
QFile file("test.txt");
if(file.exists())
{
  qDebug() << "found file";

  if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
  {
    qDebug() << "opened";

    if(file.rename("text1.txt"))
    {
      qDebug() << "renamed";
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << "failed to rename";
    }

    file.close();
  }
}
else
{
  qDebug() << "file does not exist";
}
```

In the end, you'll only really need your debugger to step through instead of printing out everything known to your application.  E.g.

```
QFile file("test.txt");
if(file.exists() && file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
  if(file.rename("text1.txt"))
  {
    qDebug() << "renamed";
  }
  file.close();
}
```